# Configuring React Navigation on web: hiding bottom tab bar based on platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Looking for general advice on best practices for adapting React Navigation for web. I would like to move the bottom tabs(in native) to the top(on web) for instance? What's a good approach for doing that? Is there a way to hide/show/change navigation based on platform?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code

Comment: @DrewReese your link refers to `react-native` (mobile) whereas the question specifies web as well.

Comment: @bilo-io Did you read the documentation, specifically the last section regarding [i.e. sharing code with NodeJS and Web](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web)? It covers platforms other than iOS/Android. React-native runs in more than just "native" platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be easier than I thought. Thank you @Drew Reese

If the following is your root navigator for instance -:

```
function RootNavigator() {

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="authNav" component={AuthNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MainNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

If you'd like for your web app to load the main navigator as a sidebar, and for your natives to load the main navigator as a bottom navigator, for example, create a bottom tabs navigator in `MainNavigator.native.js` and a sidebar(drawer navigator with drawerType set to permanent) in `MainNavigator.js.`

Even the import remains that same. Efficient!

`import MainNavigator from './MainNavigator'`

Comment: Always glad to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in at least two different ways, though I think the better one is with media queries.

#### Media queries

One way to do that is with [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), where you basically check against `screen` sizes.

You can render conditionally for current screen size being in a particular range, or smaller or larger than a particular size.

Here is a [Guide to Media Queries from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/)

> I'll abbreviate with `xs`, `sm`,`md`,`lg`,`xl` for certain sizes (`extra-small`, `small`, `medium`, `large`, `extra-large`).

In your scenario

So basically, you can then render the tabs (or any UI element, really) or hide them, or apply css conditionally.

#### User Agent

Another way you could do this is with the [User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent).

You could check for platform specific strings such as `Android`, `iPhone`, `iPad`, `Macintosh` etc.

```js
const { userAgent } = window.navigator

console.log(userAgent)
```

Comment: Thank you @bilo-io. This might have worked but it's not efficient because I am starting off from a fully function native react-native app without css for example.